# Що таке циганський випіт?

Tags: значення-слів, фразеологізми

Іван Світличний, "Випадковий сонет":

> І все ж я, випаденець, під замком
>
> Сиджу собі, некондиційний виплід,
>
> Складаю іспит на **циганський випіт**
>
> (Колись би вже….. корова язиком).

У СУМ-11 є визначення слова "випіт":

> ВИ́ПІТ, поту, чол., мед. Рідина, що збирається в тканинах і порожнинах тіла людини і тварини при запальних ураженнях.

Але вислову "циганський випіт" я знайти не можу.

Comment: Можливо, випитування, розмовне

Comment: @Sergei можливо, та поки версія bytebuster'a видається ймовірнішою.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

На мою думку, це те саме, що *циганський піт*. [Словопедія](http://slovopedia.org.ua/49/53414/362213.html):

> *цига́нський (холо́дний) піт пройма́є (охо́плює, пробира́є і т. ін.) / пройня́в (охопи́в, пробра́в і т. ін.)* кого і без додатка. Хто-небудь дрижить від нервового збудження, страху, холоду і т. ін.; когось лихоманить.
>
> - — Зосю, циганський піт не проймає тебе? — гукають подруги (М. Стельмах);
> - Холодний піт його пройма, Затіпавсь весь плечима, Що хоче пити... сил нема… Мана перед очима (П. Грабовський);
> - Танцює без чобіт (Роман), умився так умився! Оце пробрав циганський піт, оце протверезився! (П. Дорошко).

Чому автор використав слово *випіт*? Ну, напевно, для співзвучності до слів *випадок*, *випаденець*, *виплід* та інших, що починаються на `вип-` і створюють лексичну основу вірша.

Comment: Додам, що «Словопедія» (як і [«Горох»](https://goroh.pp.ua/Фразеологія/циганський)) усього-на-всього наводить фрагмент зі [«Словників України online» від УМІФ](http://lcorp.ulif.org.ua/dictua/) (які своєю чергою, імовірно, у цій статті базуються на [«Фразеологічному словнику української мови» В. Білоноженко, І. Гнатюк,
В. Горобця, В. Дятчук, В. Винника](http://chtyvo.org.ua/authors/Bilonozhenko_Vira/Frazeolohichnyi_slovnyk_ukrainskoi_movy/)).